# Guice injection null pointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, guice, code-injection

We try to refactoring a project with Guice. The idea is to bind all the *Language* interface to a concreate object like *French* or *Polish*.

We have a module for binding:

```java
public class StandardModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

       bind(Language.class).to(Polish.class);

    }
 }
```

And a classe (AboutDialog.java) that use this injected object :

```java
@Inject Language language;

public AboutDialog(JFrame parent) {
    super(parent, "", true);
    this.language=language;
    this.setTitle(language.getLanguageInUse().getString("AboutDialog.title"));
    this.parent = parent;
    try {
        jbInit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pack();
}
```

And we have as result:

```java
java.lang.NullPointerException at net.sf.jmoney.gui.AboutDialog.<init>(AboutDialog.java:67)
```

Line 67 is:

```java
this.setTitle(language.getLanguageInUse().getString("AboutDialog.title"));
```

Our interface is:

```java
public interface Language {

    public ResourceBundle getLanguageInUse();
}
```

And the Polish class is:

```java
public class Polish implements Language {

    private ResourceBundle languageInUse;

    public Polish() {
        languageInUse = ResourceBundle.getBundle(Constants.LANGUAGE_PL);
    }

    public ResourceBundle getLanguageInUse() {
        return languageInUse;
    }


}
```

We are lost...

Comment: You should change your code a little bit, to see where the NPE is thrown.
`code 
ResourceBundle bundle = language.getLanguageInUse();
String label = bundle.getString("AboutDialog.title");
`

Comment: The null object is Language. We think that the injection doesn't work.

Comment: how do you create the AboutDialog? I don't think you are creating the dialog with Guice, because Guice needs a empty constructor or do you bind jframe somewhere?

Comment: Try printing the current Thread stack trace with a log/System.out instruction in the constructor of the Polish class. In this way you can see if it is built by the Guice framework. 

Is the this.language=language; instruction really needed?

Comment: ResourceBundle can load Local-specific properties, no need to wrap it in a Language class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that your are not creating your `AboutDialog` with the help of Guice.

What you could do is use `injector.injectMembers(this)` where `this` is the `AboutDialog`.

The best way would be that the `AboutDialog` will be created by Guice, so all members will be injected.

Answer (score 14):

You're using "field injection". This will make it hard to use your injected values in a constructor; even if Guice were to create the object (which is not happening now) or you were to use `injector.injectMembers(aboutDialog)`, the constructor would run before the injector has a chance to inject the field you want.

It's a little more tricky to create a class that takes a varying parameter as well as an injected parameter. This leaves you with a few options:

- Inject the JFrame. If you know what JFrame you're going to use when the constructor is being created, then just use `bind(JFrame.class).toInstance(myJFrame);` in your Module. Then Guice can create the AboutDialog entirely.
- Create a Factory manually. That way you can inject `AboutDialog.Factory` and just call `create` to get your `AboutDialog`. It'll look something like this:

  ```
  public class AboutDialog extends JDialog {

    /** Injectable factory. */
    public static class Factory {
      @Inject private Language language;

      public AboutDialog create(JFrame parent) {
        return new AboutDialog(parent, language);
      }
    }

    // no @Inject parameter; you're calling "new" yourself above!
    public AboutDialog(JFrame parent, Language language) {
      super(parent, "", true);
      this.language = language;
      // ... other initialization
    }
  }
  ```
- Create a Factory and let Guice wire it up for you via [assisted injection](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AssistedInject).

  ```
  public class AboutDialog extends JDialog {

    public interface Factory {
      public AboutDialog create(JFrame parent);
    }

    // you need the @Inject, and also the @Assisted to tell Guice to
    // use the parameter instead of Guice bindings
    @Inject
    public AboutDialog(@Assisted JFrame parent, Language language) {
      super(parent, "", true);
      this.language = language;
      // ... other initialization
    }
  }

  public class StandardModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override protected void configure() {
      bind(Language.class).to(Polish.class);

      // here every method in AboutDialog.Factory will be implemented
      // to create the method's return type [AboutDialog] based on
      // the parameters (like JFrame) and the bindings (like Language)
      install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().build(AboutDialog.Factory.class));
    }
  }
  ```

As noted in the question comments, make sure you're getting your `AboutDialog` (or `AboutDialog.Factory` via an `@Inject`ed constructor/field or from the `Injector` itself, or else Guice will not know to inject the parameters.

Comment: We have succeed to inject the object and the project works perfectly. Thank you for your help ^^.

Comment: You're welcome! If you problem is solved please remember to [accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). Good luck with your project!

Comment: This sentence "the constructor would run before the injector has a chance to inject the field you want" saved my day, as I was not understanding why my injected fields being used inside my default construtor were allways null. Thanks!!!